# What app to use for high res webcam photo capture?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, webcam

Photo Booth does 640x480. I know the HD webcam on the 2011 MacBook Pros can do better than that. What app can I use for taking full resolution stills?

Answer (score 12):

Kinda roundabout, but you could try this:

1. Open Quicktime.
2. Choose File -> New Movie Recording.
3. On the little down arrow to the right of the record button, choose maximum quality.  Also drag the record button holder to least obtrusive location.
4. Command-3 to fit to screen.
5. Take screen shots with command-shift-(3 or 4).

Comment: Hm. Not a bad hack. Pair it with Grab for hands free pictures.

Answer (score 8):

Photo Booth in Lion does 1080x720 captures in JPEG when the hardware supports it.

Comment: You probably have a newer MBP.

Answer (score 4):

Try the free [Skitch](http://www.skitch.com/) (also available from the [Mac App Store](http://skit.ch/mas)). One of the many things it can do is a Cam Snapshot. To take one, invoke Skitch, then choose Capture > Cam Snapshot. You may need to fiddle a bit with the size of the snapshot to get full resolution.

This worked to the max resolution of the iSight on my older MacBook Pro; it's worth a try on the current models with their FaceTime HD cameras.

Comment: Cam snapshot is no longer an option in current Skitch sadly.

Answer (score 3):

I searched for that too. The best option for me was to use VLC.

- Open VLC
- Type <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
- Choose your camera and the resolution that you want (that your camera is capable of)
- Then type <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to take a snapshot within VLC (aka your photo)

You can also tweak the settings of VLC to chose the name of your output ([which can contain variables](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Snapshots/)), and its type (png, jpg, tiff).

Answer (score 0):

[Quicky by BlackOp](http://b-l-a-c-k-o-p.com/Quicky.html) is my choice.  it lets you do lossless webcam video capture.  I then do a frame dump from the video with Quicktime Pro 7

Answer (score 0):

The app Macnification from Orbicule is free, captures high resolution images, allows things like measurements and calibration for microcopes. It is at: http://www.orbicule.com/macnification/

However it is dated, probably won't work with Catalina, is unsigned and comes from a non https secured website.