# Capture Photo from webcam on MacOS

Tags: macos, photos, webcam

i know there is similar question but it was like 8 years ago,

I need an application that will take a picture with my external web camera connected to a computer via USB. I can't find anything like that - logitech doesn't have such macos software

solutions I've tried with reference to:
[What app to use for high res webcam photo capture?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/15856/what-app-to-use-for-high-res-webcam-photo-capture)

quicktime player:
It allows you to display high quality live image. but quicktime has no built-in capability to take snapshots. I'd have to manually take snapshots via CMD + Shift + 4 - this is not an option

Photo Both:
it works, but the pictures are in very low (640x480) resolution, the camera is 1280x720

VLC:
this would be the best solution because there is a keyboard shortcut to take pictures, but unfortunately my camera lags a lot in the VLC program.
I tried to change the buffering time but this does not solve the problem